# Framer Motion: How can I animate the timescale of the animation without interrupting it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, gsap, framer-motion

Using Framer Motion, I created a Marquee component that infinitely and linearly moves. What I want is on hover, slowly make the marquee slower.

Here are my code.

```js
{divisions.map((chipset, i) => (
        <motion.div
          animate={{
            x: ["-50%", "0%"],
          }}
          transition={{
            x: {
              repeat: Infinity,
              repeatType: "loop",
              duration: 5,
              ease: "linear",
            },
          }}
          key={`chipset-${i}`}
          className={clsx("relative flex h-8 w-fit")}
        >
          {new Array(2).fill(null).map((_, j) =>
            chipset.map(({ name, color, url }, k) => (
              <Link
                className="mr-[5px]"
                key={`${name}-${i}-${j}-${k}`}
                href={url}
                target="_blank"
              >
                <Chip {...{ color }}>{name}</Chip>
              </Link>
            )),
          )}
        </motion.div>
      ))}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

What I tried is to use a `MotionValue` and bind it to the duration. However, that didn't work. Also, I tried using `useAnimationControls`. That didn't work, as well. Using GSAP, I animated the `timeScale` and got the desired result but couldn't find any way to do the same in Framer Motion. Can you help me?